# Help solving the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to evaluate the following limit: $$\displaystyle\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3}.$$ Can someone help me how to solve it? I don't want the result but the solution.

Comment: What have you tried ? What are your problems with this question ? Please use appropriate tag(s) next time, the tag (derivatives) is for question about derivatives of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $2^{\ln n} = n^{\ln 2}$ and so
$$
\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3}=
\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{\ln 2}}{n^3}=0
$$
because $\ln 2 < 3$.

Comment: That's awesome! Helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

since $2 < e$ you have for $n$ sufficiently big $0 \leq \frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3} \leq \frac{e^{\ln n}}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n^2} \rightarrow 0 $

Comment: well, actually for all $n$ since $\ln n$ is always non-negative

Comment: Thank you. Helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\ln n}}{n^3}\cdot \frac{n^3}{e^{3 \ln n}} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{e^3}\right)^{\ln n} \\
\frac{2}{e^3} < 1 \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{e^3}\right)^{k} = 0 \\
$$

Comment: Thanks for you're answer :)